# How to plot a heatmap with a color hex as the z direction component (plotly or ggplot prefered)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I want to plot a figure where my third dimension (Z) is defined by a color hex which is defined by the make up of three values.

I have already converted three values into a hex using rgb(). I now have a data frame which has the x and y values as numbers and a z column with a bunch of hex values.

Is there a way to create a plot where each point is colored by the hex value, whether that is by creating a heat map in plotly or using geom_raster/geom_tile in ggplot2.

If there is another package that I could use thats fine too.

Here is some code to show what I have done thus far

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
cap_1 <- runif(9,0,10)
cap_2 <- runif(9,0,10)
cap_3 <- runif(9,0,10)
df <- data.frame(x,y,cap_1,cap_2, cap_3)
```

I convert the capacity (cap_1 to cap_3) into percentages and then create a color hex based on the primary colors from the percentages

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(cap_sum = rowSums(df[3:5])) %>%
    mutate(cap_1_p = cap_1/cap_sum) %>%
    mutate(cap_2_p = cap_2/cap_sum) %>%
    mutate(cap_3_p = cap_3/cap_sum) %>%
    mutate(z = rgb(cap_1_p, cap_2_p,cap_3_p))
```

I have tried plotting it as a heat map unsuccessfully:

```
library(plotly)
fig <- plot_ly(df, x='x', y='y', z='z', 
           type = "heatmap")
fig
```

Comment: Can you share code and data to make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I made some edits to the questions with code. The question is really about the last lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach going through `ggplot` and on to `ggplotly`:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_identity()
plotly::ggplotly(g)
```

[image]